# Dictionary lookup in django templates

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

```
{% for dispN0, tableDataSet0 in tabulatedTable.items %}
    {% for dispN in orderChanels %}     
        {% for antenaName, antenaLevel in tableDataSet0.{{dispN}}.items %}  
             <td>{{antenaName}}</td>    
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here **{{dispN}}** is integers numbers will come..like 36, 42, etc. If i give **tableDataSet0.36.items** it's working fine. But I need multiples in the place 36.

Comment: You need to write an own template filter. You can't access variables with other variables in python without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write an own [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) to lookup the value of a dictionary or an object:

Create a file like `utils.py` within a `templatetags` folder within your app like this:

```
app_dir/
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
  ...
├── templatetags/
│   ├── __init__.py  # required for python 2.7
│   └── utils.py
  ...
└── views.py
```

And fill it with this content:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def lookup(value, key):
    return value.get(key, [])
```

Now you can use this filter in your template like this:

```
{% load utils %}

{% for dispN0, tableDataSet0 in tabulatedTable.items %}
    {% for dispN in orderChanels %}

        {% with tableData = tableDataSet0|lookup:dispN %}
            {% for antenaName, antenaLevel in tableData.items %}
                <td>{{antenaName}}</td> 
            {% endfor %}
        {% endwith %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Read more about

- [Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)
- [the `{% with %}` templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Comment: where can I find that option?